# Unable to pass parameter as input to AWS Lambda function from AWS step function

Tags: aws-step-functions, aws-event-bridge

Unable to pass parameter as input json to AWS Lambda function from AWS step function. When I have hardcoded the parameter within step function definition it is working. Following is the parameter structure:

"Parameters":{
"Payload": {
"namespace" : "ABC",
"jobname" : "Job1",
"jobversion" "1",
"jobenvironmentveriavle": [
{
"name" : "PROFILE"
"value" : "dev"
},
{
"name" : "ID"
"value" : "12345"
}
]
},
"FunctionName": "AWS Lambda ARN"
}

When I try to pass only JSON like following way it working
{
"namespace" : "ABC",
"jobname" : "Job1",
"jobversion" "1"
}

But unable to pass array within JSON as input to AWS Step function (pass payload using input text bos/area when start the execution). Always array part within json is going to step function as null hence AWS Lambda also getting null.

Try to pass multiple way Json and array of key value within it but it did not worked and want to remove hardcoded parameter from AWS Step function definition so that same step function can be used my multiple event bridge just by changing the parameter and invole different logic in Lambda

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a colon after the key: `jobversion` and comma (,) inside your array, between the elements ? The correct JSON for you should be:

```json
{
    "Parameters": {
        "Payload": {
            "namespace": "ABC",
            "jobname": "Job1",
            "jobversion": "1",
            "jobenvironmentveriavle": [
                {
                    "name": "PROFILE",
                    "value": "dev"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ID",
                    "value": "12345"
                }
            ]
        },
        "FunctionName": "AWS Lambda ARN"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you are incorrectly assigning parameters in the Lambda Task invoke such as `$.Parameters.Payload` or you are not able to correctly collect the parameters in the lambda method itself something like `event['Payload']`. Closely look at the Step function `Parameters` and the Lambda function `event` parameter usages.

I have tried the simple Step function below:

```
{
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:<YourAccountNumber>:function:trigger-from-step-function-with-parameters:$LATEST",
  "Parameters": {
    "Payload.$": "$.Payload"
  },
  "ResultPath": "$.LambdaResponse",
  "End": true
}
```

And the lambda function is as below:

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(event['Payload'])
}
```

With the below formatted JSON (You can format JSON within the input box of the AWS step function for any possible error in your JSON)

```
{
  "Payload": {
    "namespace": "ABC",
    "jobname": "Job1",
    "jobversion": "1",
    "jobenvironmentveriavle": [
      {
        "name": "PROFILE",
        "value": "dev"
      },
      {
        "name": "ID",
        "value": "12345"
      }
    ]
  },
  "FunctionName": "AWS Lambda ARN"
}
```

And it works as expected, see the screenshots:

[image]
[image]

With the response is as below:

```
"LambdaResponse": {
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "{\"namespace\": \"ABC\", \"jobname\": \"Job1\", \"jobversion\": \"1\", \"jobenvironmentveriavle\": [{\"name\": \"PROFILE\", \"value\": \"dev\"}, {\"name\": \"ID\", \"value\": \"12345\"}]}"
}
```

'